# Problem with living web page - I want to replace the <pre> tags with <div> tags on living document, in browser

Tags: html, browser

There is this very nice article about threading in python.
http://www.laurentluce.com/posts/python-threads-synchronization-locks-rlocks-semaphores-conditions-events-and-queues/

article is awesome, but that is off-topic.

When you scroll down, you can see, that some paragraphs are cut, and invisible (beginning around Lock section header). When you inspect the source, you see that its caused by `<pre>` tags wrapping several sections.
Is there any way to replace all `<pre>` tags to, lets say `<div>` tags on living document?
Maybe plugin to chrome/Mozilla/opera - whatever. I don't want to manually replace them one by one in inspection tool

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found the solution. 
I downloaded whole page (r click > save as...) to a folder. 
Then I opened it in editor (lets say Sublime Text) and replaced all `<pre>` and `</pre>` tags with `<div>` and `</div>`.
*Viola* :P